# Tests within Gem need to test migration generator and apply migrations for tests

Tags: ruby, testing, tdd, rubygems, rails-migrations

I'm working on a Gem that contains a migration generator and a bunch of models, classes, etc that utilize the tables created as part of the migration.

Although testing the migration generator itself is easy enough - there's loads of tutorials around for getting that done, what i'm trying to work out is how to actually run the migration on the test DB so I can later test how the gem interacts with the test data?

Since the gem doesn't have a schema.rb, I wasn't sure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I run migrations in code;

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3", :database => ":memory:")
  ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false

  @migration  = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Migration) do

    def change
      create_table :users, :force => true do |t|
        t.string     :roles_mask
      end
      create_table :user_without_roles, :force => true do |t|
        t.string     :roles_mask
      end
      create_table :user_without_role_masks, :force => true do |t|
      end
    end

  end

  @migration.new.migrate(:up)
```

If you have a string containing your generated migration you could do something like this in your test setup;

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3", :database => ":memory:")
  ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false

  # Or however you intend to grab the output of the migration generator
  migration_string = ERB.new(File.read(<file name here>)).result

  migration  = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Migration)
  migration.class_eval(migration_string)
  migration.new.migrate(:up)
```

That should give you a migrated database using the migration you've generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

I am going to assume you're using ActiveRecord. So in your test helper you should setup a in-memory database:

```
require 'active_record'

# Connection must be establised before anything else
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => defined?(JRUBY_VERSION) ? 'jdbcsqlite3' : 'sqlite3',
  :database => ':memory:'
)
```

Then invoke the rake task within your test. This would look something like:

```
require 'rake'
requie File.expand_path('../Rakefile', __FILE__) # you'll need to modify this path to actually point to the Rakefile

Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
```

The rake taks invocation is untested, but that should point you in the right direction.

The other option would be to just run the command:

```
%x{rake db:migrate}
```